# How to count the number of records per hour?

Tags: sql, t-sql

In SQL I'm trying to find the number patients that are currently in our Emergency Department. Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT CAST(dt_ARRIVAL AS DATE) [Date], 
DATEPART(HOUR,dt_ARRIVAL) [Hour], Count(1)  [Patients]
FROM [Hospital].[dbo].[DATA_DUMP]
WHERE dt_ARRIVAL >= '2016-04-15'
GROUP BY CAST(dt_ARRIVAL AS DATE), DATEPART(HOUR,dt_ARRIVAL)
ORDER BY 1 ,2
```

It gives me the number of patients that arrived at that hour as shown here:

```
Date    Hour    Patients
4/15/16  2       2
4/15/16  4       1
4/15/16  6       1
4/15/16  7       5
4/15/16  8       2
```

This doesn't account for all patients, like ones that are in beds or are in the waiting room. I thought I could use a "departure" time stamp called dt_departure to calculate this but that is where I am stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is some data from the table that I've scrubbed patient identifiers:

```
dt_ARRIVAL      dt_DEPARTURE    s_OUTCOME_LOCATION   _OUTCOME_ID
4/20/2016 4:49  4/20/2016 5:24  D:Home/Self Care            2
4/20/2016 5:49  4/20/2016 9:30  H:Med-Surg 2, CPH213-1      1
4/20/2016 7:01  4/20/2016 11:10 H:Observation, OBS250-3     1
4/20/2016 7:34  NULL            NULL                     NULL
```

Comment: You need to show us some example data. Also please make sure it is scrubbed or mocked up data. We don't know what you have captured in your table

Comment: I added a link to some data in my original post.

Comment: Can you post that scrubbed sample here please? Links to file sharing age and will be unusable to future answer seekers.

Comment: I posted the data.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data constructs it is a little hard but

```
SELECT CAST(dt_ARRIVAL AS DATE) [Date], 
DATEPART(HOUR,dt_ARRIVAL) [Hour], Count(1)  [Patients]
FROM [Hospital].[dbo].[DATA_DUMP]
WHERE dt_ARRIVAL >= '2016-04-15' AND dt_DEPART=''
GROUP BY CAST(dt_ARRIVAL AS DATE), DATEPART(HOUR,dt_ARRIVAL)
ORDER BY 1 ,2
```

My assumption here is that something like `dt_DEPART=''` would exclude patients who have exited.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(dt_ARRIVAL AS DATE) [Date]
     , DATEPART(HOUR,dt_ARRIVAL) [Hour], Count(1)  [Patients]
FROM [Hospital].[dbo].[DATA_DUMP]
WHERE dt_ARRIVAL >= '2016-04-15' 
GROUP BY CAST(dt_ARRIVAL AS DATE), DATEPART(HOUR,dt_ARRIVAL) 
union all 
select cast('1900-01-01' as date), 0, count(*)  
FROM [Hospital].[dbo].[DATA_DUMP]
WHERE dt_ARRIVAL is null
ORDER BY 1 ,2;
```

But I am surprised you could have someone entered without an dt_ARRIVAL
How can someone be in a bed that did not have a dt_ARRIVAL?
Seems like that should be a required field

Comment: There is always a dt_ARRIVAL, I will try and post some data.

Comment: Then your question makes no sense.  How could it miss people waiting or in beds if that column has (valid) data?

Comment: Because my query only counts the number of patients that arrived in the ED at that hour.

Comment: Not kidding dt_ARRIVAL is arrival.  You have failed to described what you need.  Or why that misses any. Answer is only as good as the question.

Comment: Correct, each new patient visit is a new row in the database so there is always a dt_ARRIVAL. If you look at the sample I updated above, in the case where there are NULL values, that means the patient is still in the ED. I can't figure out how to properly count everyone, past visits per hour and patients that are still in the ED.

Comment: Knock, knock.  I have given up trying to help you.  Learn to articulate a question and someone else may try and help you.